# time scale displays wrong year

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a timescale axis with only years as tick labels but the year displayed is wrong. With the sample code below it shows as : "1951  1952  1953  1953  1954". It looks like a roundoff error as if you show the month it switches from January to December: "Jan-1951  Jan-1952  Jan-1953  Dec-1953  Dec 1954..."

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 3000)
                                    .attr("height", 300);

var axisScale = d3.time.scale()
                  .domain([new Date("1950-11-11"), new Date("1980-07-14")])
                  .range([0, 3000])
                  .nice(d3.time.year);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(axisScale)
              .ticks(d3.time.year, 1)
              .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svgContainer.append("g").call(xAxis);
```

**Update**: The bug only shows in Firefox (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqoJt.jpg). So it's probably down to JS implementation differences.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s7pytbbq/

Comment: Thanks. Seems it only happens on Firefox. Description updated